# Why are "Wiener chaos" called like that?

Tags: probability-theory, soft-question, stochastic-calculus, math-history

This is a *very soft* question, but I was wondering from where does the term "Chaos" come, in the Wiener chaos theory?

Comment: It has been studied by Norbert Wiener in ["The Homogeneous Chaos", American Journal of Mathematics (1938)](http://oerior.uniud.it/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Wiener1938.pdf)

Comment: See also [Chaos theory: History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory#History)